# Link multiple object files in gfortran

Tags: compilation, makefile, linker, fortran, gfortran

I have "library" folder with multiple object (.o) files. These files contain subroutines which are not changing from project to project. Each new project uses some of those object files, but not all of them.
Could you please tell me is there any way to tell **gfortran** to look up that folder for necessary .o files?
I've tried -I and -L options, but no way. When I write .o names directly, it works:
`gfortran main.for ./library/obj1.o ./library/obj2.o`
 but I have many of .o files and write all of them waste time.
I could write
 `gfortran main.for ./*.o`
 but then main program will be linked with all .o files, but it needs only some of them.
I hoped that something like
 `gfortran main.for -L./library/`
 will work, but it doesn't.
I use OS X with gcc version 5.1.0.
And I'm pretty sure that I should use makefile for such case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing object files with static libraries. An object file
is not a static library and the gfortran linker - which is simply
the GNU system linker, invoked by `gfortran` - will not treat it as such.
You need a static library and you are trying to use object files in lieu.

The linker recognizes an object file by the extension `.o`. It recognizes
a static library by the extension `.a`, and it expects the *contents* of an `.a` file
to have the form of a static library, not the format of an object file. (So you
cannot make an object file into a static library just by renaming it).

The linker will link into your program every object file that appears on its
commandline, whether or not it is needed. It does not expect you to mention
object files if you don't want them linked. The linker options `-L` and `-l` for
locating *libraries* have no application to object files.

A static library is a fairly simple archive containing some number of
object files, plus a house-keeping header and typically an index of the
public symbols defined in the contained object files.

When the linker encounters a static library on its commandline, it does not
link the entire contents of the library (unless you expressly tell it to). It inspects
the contained object files to determine which, if any, of them contain
definitions for symbols that are as yet undefined at that point in the linkage
of the program. If any object file in the library is found to provide any
of the missing definitions, then that object file is extracted from the library
and linked into the program. *Object files in the library that provide no
missing definitions are not linked*. Libraries on the commandline are sequentially
inspected in this way until either all the symbols referred to by the program 
have definitions in linked object files or there are no more libraries.

If as you say the object files that you are trying to use as libraries are stable
resources that you never have to build for your projects, then you can just make a static
library out of them and link that library with your per-project programs.

To make a static library from object files, use the [`ar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29) tool. 
See `man ar`.

When you have made your library, say, `libsubs.a`, and have decided it shall reside
in some directory, `/path/to/subs`, then you link it with a program by adding

```
    -L/path/to/subs -lsubs
```

to the commandline in which your program is linked. This will cause the linker
to search for a library called `libsubs.a` in directory `/path/to/subs`.

So if you are compiling and linking in a single step, use it like:

```
gfortran -o myprog myprog.f90 -L/path/to/subs -lsubs
```

And if you are compiling and linking in distinct steps, use it like:

```
gfortran -c -o myprog_1st_file.o myprog_1st_file.f90
gfortran -c -o myprog_2nd_file.o myprog_2nd_file.f90
gfortran -o myprog myprog_1st_file.o myprog_2nd_file.o -L/path/to/subs -lsubs
```

This is how you are supposed to use a set of object file resources of which
different subsets will be required for linkage with different programs: you put
them in a library and link the library.

Comment: Awesome! You described exactly what I needed. Don't know why I missed idea to organize all object files into static lib. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And one more thing)
What if I need to make temporary changes in one subroutine in static lib?
For example, I have subroutine named **CALC**, in `calc.o`. I pack `calc.o` with many others `.o` files into static lib. But during developing I need to add some temporary changes to `calc.o`. If I put together `MainProgram.for` and `calc.for` and compile&link them with lib, linker will say, that I have duplicated reference for **CALC**. Is it possible to tell linker, that if it already found subroutine in object file, than it should not link it from lib?

Comment: You simply need to put your specialized version of `calc.o` earlier in the linkage than the static library. As I explained, the linker will extract and link an object file from a static library only if that object file provides definitions of some symbols that remain undefined at that point in the linkage. If your `calc.o` defines all the same symbols as the library's version then if your `calc.o` is linked first, the library's version is ignored.